Diagonal matrix from vector
Using faer crate, I'm trying to create a diagonal matrix from a vector:
use faer::{Mat}

fn foo(
  vector: &[f64],
) -> Mat<f64> {

  // convert inputs to faer matrix
  let vector_faer = Mat::from_fn(1, vector.len(), |_, col| vector[col]);
  
  Mat::column_vector_as_diagonal(&vector_faer);

Despite rust-analyzer doesn't shows any warning, it panics (see below for n = 5). What am I missing?
Assertion failed: self.ncols() == 1
- self.ncols() = 5
- 1 = 1


What is the panic message? Backtrace?

@ChayimFriedman added

Turns out I was trying to use Mat::column_vector_as_diagonal() with a row vector instead of a column vector. Correct would be
// convert inputs to faer matrix
  let vector_faer = Mat::from_fn(vector.len(), 1, |row, _| vector[row]);


You might have fixed the error, but the business logic does not look right, because you are getting just the first n elements from the vector.
If what you want is to interpret the vector as a whole matrix and then extract the diagonal elements you can do this:
Mat::from_fn(n, n, |row, col| 
    if row != col { 0.0 } else { vector[col + (n*row)] }
)

Or you can get the diagonal as one column as you wanted:
Mat::from_fn(n, 1, |row, _| 
    vector[n*row + row%n]
)

This would fix your initial error as well, so you can call Mat::column_vector_as_diagonal(&vector_faer); but you didn't tell why you want to do that.

No, I don't want to do that. I've got a 1xn vector, not a row-major matrix as a vector. I want to create a diagonal matrix from it, not create a matrix and then extract the diagonal. But I understand why you'd think that: that n = vector.len().sqrt(), which works for nxn matrices is just a leftover from the original code when I've wrote this reprex. Thanks, I've edited that out.
